# Is there a way to pass an rvalue by reference in C++?

Tags: c++, stack, binary-search-tree, rvalue, lvalue

I'm trying to create "rollback" functionality for a small database assignment.
I have a stack of binary search trees that I am using to store backups of the database called:

```
GenStack<GenBST<Student>> masterStudentStack;
```

Both the stack and BST are my own implementations (per the instructions for my assignment).

I have no problem pushing a copy of the BST onto the stack,

```
masterStudentStack.push(*masterStudent);
```

however when I try to retrieve this BST and return it to my primary BST pointer
using:

```
void rollBack() {
    masterStudent = new GenBST<Student>(masterStudentStack.pop());
}
```

I receive an error.

```
Menu.cpp:419:63: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of 
type ‘GenBST<Student>&’ from an rvalue of type ‘GenBST<Student>’
 masterStudent = new GenBST<Student>(masterStudentStack.pop());
                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
In file included from Menu.h:7:0,
             from Menu.cpp:1:
GenBST.h:49:1: note:   initializing argument 1 of 
‘GenBST<T>::GenBST(GenBST<T>&) [with T = Student]’
 GenBST<T>::GenBST(GenBST<T>& other) {
 ^~~~~~~~~
```

The copy constructor for the BST is functional when an lvalue is passed in by reference, (this is the declaration for the constructor)

```
GenBST(GenBST<T>& other);
```

but I don't know how to pop something off the stack in a way in which the copy constructor will accept it.  So, my question is: Can I something create a new BST using the rvalue "stack.pop()"?

Thanks,
Matthew

Edit:

After adding "const" to my BST copy constructor, I got this error

```
In file included from Menu.h:7:0,
             from Menu.cpp:1:
GenBST.h: In instantiation of ‘GenBST<T>::GenBST(const GenBST<T>&) [with T = 
Student]’:
Menu.cpp:419:65:   required from here
GenBST.h:50:22: error: passing ‘const GenBST<Student>’ as ‘this’ argument 
discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
   if(other.getRoot() == NULL) {

GenBST.h:77:17: note:   in call to ‘GenTreeNode<T>* GenBST<T>::getRoot() 
[with T = Student]’
 GenTreeNode<T>* GenBST<T>::getRoot()
                 ^~~~~~~~~
GenBST.h:54:32: error: binding ‘GenTreeNode<Student>* const’ to reference of 
type ‘GenTreeNode<Student>*&’ discards qualifiers
     copyTree(this->root, other.root);
                          ~~~~~~^~~~
GenBST.h:108:6: note:   initializing argument 2 of ‘void 
GenBST<T>::copyTree(GenTreeNode<T>*&, GenTreeNode<T>*&) [with T = Student]’
 void GenBST<T>::copyTree(GenTreeNode<T> *& thisNode, GenTreeNode<T> *& 
otherNode) {
```

Here is my constructor and the method it calls:

```
template <class T>
GenBST<T>::GenBST(const GenBST<T>& other) {
  if(other.getRoot() == NULL) {
    root = NULL;
  }
  else {
    copyTree(this->root, other.root);
  }
}

template <class T>
void GenBST<T>::copyTree(GenTreeNode<T> *& thisNode, GenTreeNode<T> *& 
otherNode) {
  if(otherNode == NULL) {
    thisNode = NULL;
  }
  else {
    thisNode = new GenTreeNode<T>(otherNode->key);
    copyTree(thisNode->left, otherNode->left);
    copyTree(thisNode->right, otherNode->right);
  }
}
```

Any ideas?

Edit 2:

Thank so much for the help everybody.  I added const to both my getRoot() and copyTree() methods and am now down to one error.

```
GenBST.h: In instantiation of ‘GenBST<T>::GenBST(const GenBST<T>&) [with T = 
Student]’:
Menu.cpp:419:65:   required from here
GenBST.h:54:32: error: binding ‘GenTreeNode<Student>* const’ to reference of 
type ‘GenTreeNode<Student>*&’ discards qualifiers
     copyTree(this->root, other.root);
                          ~~~~~~^~~~
GenBST.h:108:6: note:   initializing argument 2 of ‘void 
GenBST<T>::copyTree(GenTreeNode<T>*&, GenTreeNode<T>*&) const [with T = 
Student]’
 void GenBST<T>::copyTree(GenTreeNode<T> *& thisNode, GenTreeNode<T> *& 
otherNode) const {
```

Comment: you also need to make `getRoot()` and `copyTree` be const methods

Comment: Also you probably shouldn't be using `new` and `delete` with `masterStudent` (it could be a `GenBST` instead of a pointer to one , since you seem to be using value semantics with it anyway)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The canonical form of a copy constructor takes a reference to a const object to copy. Conceptually, making a copy of something normally implies that the original object remains unchanged. There should hardly ever be a need to modify the object you're copying. An rvalue can be bound to a reference to const but not to a reference to non-const. Unless making a copy of a `GenBST` really does actually entail modifying the object you're copying (I assume and sincerely hope it does not), you can simply change the signature of your copy constructor to

```
GenBST(const GenBST& other);
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! I tried this, but it resulted in a different error that I don't quite understand. I'll attach it to my original post.

Comment: Well, the problem is that `const` is transitive. Your `copyTree()` method expects references to non-const objects but you give it references to objects that are now `const`. You'll have to add `const` there too. With [const-correctness](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness) it's all or nothing…